# Ubuntu Unity top panel buttons are stuck at lockscreen

Tags: unity, 18.04, mouse, lightdm, lock-screen

**Prerequisites:**

- Updated from 16.04 to 18.04
- Using LightDM + Unity (GDM is not an options since VNC has problems with it, Gnome is not an option since it has bug with non-latin layout for lockscreen)

**Problem:**

- In two-monitor setup after locking screen and moving cursor to another screen and back, all tray buttons are stuck like in picture below, thus forcing me to reboot system (I connect through VNC).
- Initial login screen never has this issue and works just fine.

This is how it looks:

[image: Stuck buttons]

Steps to reproduce for me with 100% chance:

1. Lock screen
2. Move mouse pointer to another monitor
3. Move pointer back to main screen
4. All buttons after pressing start to behave like this